# How to get a full back up and recover a system based on that?

Tags: backup

What is the best way to get a full back up of an Ubuntu (including drivers, installed applications, etc) and later if needed recover the system with that backup? Something like getting a snapshot and return to it if needed.

Comment: You can read the Arch Wiki page on system backup. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/System_backup